# Question deleted in 2011 is on-topic in 2022

Tags: support, closed-questions, deleted-posts

I suggest that the following question, which is deleted and invisible to users with less than 10K reputation, ought to be undeleted.
[What is the English equivalent to the Russian proverb ""За битого - двух небитых дают"? [closed]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/help-me-to-translate-the-russian-proverb-%d0%97%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82) ([image for < 10k users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozqtV.jpg))

In 2011 the question was closed and deleted because at the time it was viewed to be purely a Russian translation request. However, as most users are aware, EL&U does accept requests for idioms, expressions, and proverbs. This is one such request, the difference being the OP knew one in Russian but not its English equivalent. As a result, the title has been edited to reflect more truthfully the OP's intention.

I would like to ask the community for their opinion and consider casting their vote to undelete the question and then to reopen it. Thank you!

Comment: How did you even find this question? Just curious.

Comment: @Laurel Found it in the archives of meta, [an extensive list of deleted questions by the same OP](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/738/), this had the potential for being an interesting question. The others were written very confusingly.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to resurrect  a question without the author's involvement. SE is a collaboration, and the question's author should be part of that collaboration. If you think that is an interesting question, you should ask it, explaining where it came from. That way you can accept the answer *that was most helpful to you*. You don't have to know Russian to be able to judge the answers, because a good answer will include sources and explanation enough for you to be reasonably sure it is correct.

Comment: @ColleenV Good general point re OP involvement. But it is an interesting, on-topic, question and topical question which could easily outweigh those issues. I've voted to reopen.

Comment: @Mitch Well, I can't see the question or get an idea of how extensive the edits were, so it's hard for me to have an opinion about the content of the question. I feel though that if a question has been deleted for years, and requires extensive edits to whip it into shape so it can be opened, the site would be better served by someone using it as the basis for a new question. Although, it's probably less important now that we can follow questions and get notified of all activity on them even though we aren't the author.

Comment: @ColleenV Mari-Lou edited it and (in my opinion) it doesn't need any more.

Comment: @ColleenV I basically reworded the title and inproved the grammar in the body. The two upvoted answers that are also deleted  will not be harmed by the edit. EDIT  I see that Laurel has kindly included a screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question has now been undeleted and re-opened.

[What is the English equivalent to the Russian proverb "За битого - двух небитых дают"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/what-is-the-english-equivalent-to-the-russian-proverb-%d0%97%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b%d1%85)

Comment: Many thanks to those users who cast their votes to undelete and reopen the post. Yay!

Answer (score 2):

I see no real benefit in resuscitating the dead question, belonging to a user who is no longer on ELU.

I see good improvement after your edit, and I think you would have a better reception if you posted a new question using the information in it. It certainly won't be closed as a duplicate of the deleted one. And there aren't any valuable answers in the deleted one currently that deserves a second chance.

Comment: But I don't speak Russian. How can I judge which answer is best whereas we have Russian speakers who also know English.

Comment: That particular user won't be returning to judge the answers either.

Comment: But EL&U does have users who are Russian speakers...

Comment: And those Russian speaking ELU users will vote on your new question signaling to you what answer works best. My two cents.

Comment: Due to SE's aim of being a repository, having an absent author isn't considered to be a particularly serious shortcoming so long as the question itself is interesting (within the scope of the community, of course). The only problem with having an absent author is that the question can't be given the green tick. But that's a minor problem if the question can attract good answers.