# Should we link to resources for learning English in order to prevent scope-creep?

Tags: discussion, scope, site

As discussed in questions like [this](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/703/is-elu-becoming-esl) and [this](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/is-english-stackexchange-com-used-for-increase), there is the possibility of scope-creep on this site. Would it be beneficial to link to any resources that are better places than this site to start learning English? For example, could we add this to the "About" or "FAQ" page? I know they're basically boilerplate pages that all SE sites use, but we get enough questions about this that I think it's worth discussing the possibilities, or reasons why we shouldn't.

Comment: sure, have the community mods edit the top part of your /faq to taste

Comment: @Jasper Loy: I'm not sure off the top of my head. We could ask the community for suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

To summarise comments:

Yes, we should. We need to come up with a list of sites to include in the FAQ and then our community mods can edit the top part of our /faq.

Let's compile the list [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2093/what-resources-should-we-link-to-for-learning-english).