# What resources should we link to in the FAQ for learning English?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic

(Following on from [this meta question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/should-we-link-to-resources-for-learning-english-in-order-to-prevent-scope-creep).)

As discussed in questions like [this](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/703/is-elu-becoming-esl) and [this](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/is-english-stackexchange-com-used-for-increase), there is the possibility of scope-creep on this site. It would be beneficial to link to resources that are better places than this site to start learning English.

We get enough questions about this, so we should add something to the top part of our FAQ.

**What resources should we link to for learning English?**

Comment: In before someone mentions Strunk & White and lots of other people denounce it.

Answer (score 3):

Jane Straus's [The Blue Book of Grammar and Punctuation](http://grammarbook.com/) gives common grammar and punctuation rules with an emphasis on AmE.

Larry Trask's [The Penguin Guide to Punctuation](http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/department/docs/punctuation/node00.html) gives a rather detailed treatment of punctuation with an emphasis on BrE.

Each is available online and in print.