# Why was this question about discussion of grammar and programming closed?

Tags: support, appropriate-questions, closed-questions

[Is there a forum or discussion group to discuss programmatically editing English grammar and spelling in texts?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88022/is-there-a-forum-or-discussion-group-to-discuss-programmatically-editing-english#comment176246_88022)

This is a perfectly good question that can be very specifically answered. It asks about where one can engage further discuss the rules of English grammar in relation to programming.  Possible answers include:

> *check out grammarprogrammingforum.com. they discuss various algorithms for automatically checking and correcting texts.*

or

> *there is a computer science club at soandso.edu where they discuss linguistics in programming. They have a mailing list, here is a link where you can get more information and sign up.*

Instead of just arbitrarily closing the question, why not offer some advice as to why and suggestions on how to improve? I am going to ask the question again, so please advice on a better way to phrase my question so it's not just simply closed again.

Answer (score 6):

Here are some random thoughts off the top of my head in no particular order.

- One problem is — which is why Martha mentioned "not constructive" —, your question is very open-ended. A bigger problem still: it's more open-ended than it need be. People will start googling for the same things you already googled for, suggesting things you already rejected, linking to forums that only discuss programming in Turbo Pascal 5.5, and only in Bulgarian. These will all be perfectly valid answers and yet not help you one bit. In short, [you very likely have a number of rather specific constraints, but you mention none at all](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). So people tend to see this as "not constructive" or "not a real question".
- Again, as Martha mentions, two years from now half the links will be dead, or point to something else entirely. So people tend to see this as "too localized".
- Lastly, since *this site* here is not "a forum or discussion group to discuss programmatically editing English grammar and spelling in text", it also is, by definition, not the best venue to *ask* where else such a forum or discussion group can be found. It's like going to a site about cooking, and asking for links to forums about playing guitar. It's a safe bet that there are people around who totally *can* answer your question; but it's a bet nonetheless. So people tend to see such questions as "off-topic". No one will prevent you from dropping by in our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage), though, and asking there.

I have read [your reasoning](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2207/should-not-the-faq-have-an-entry-about-online-resource-questions/3231#3231) on the online-resource questions. I see your point. Yes, arguably *every* question can be deemed subjective; I'll go further myself: every question on every Q&A site ever is a straw poll of a random group of strangers off the Internet. And yes, arguably every question is too localized — English is a living language, so soon enough *all* answers on this site will be outdated. That much is true.

But that's too broad a definition of "subjective" or "too localized"; we can't work with that. We have to draw the line somewhere. And it just so happens that we draw it here. It's drawn but in sand, though, not set in stone. The very fact that there is an open meta question on which you could post your thoughts is indication that the exact guidelines are work in progress.

Answer (score 2):

See [this question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2207/should-not-the-faq-have-an-entry-about-online-resource-questions). Bottom line, resource requests are out of scope for this site: every answer is equally valid, and all answers are subject to going out-of-date unusually fast. (I would've closed your question as "not constructive", not "not a real question", but that's just 'cause I'm a pedant.)

Comment: +1, and even if resource requests were on topic, I would probably consider this one to be too localized.

Comment: I humbly disagree with the reasoning in that question. Here is an answer I hope sheds a different perspective on why questions like these are important. http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/3231/24811

Comment: @user658182: The answer you linked to has vote score of -2, and there is a comment on one of the other answers to that question stating:  "Questions asking about books, or online resources are closed as "not constructive" in all the Stack Exchange sites."  So while you have every right to disagree, the SE stance seems pretty clear on the matter.

Answer (score 2):

You may also have seen the comment posted there:

> You may find better help on linguisticsSE. Meanwhile, note that you **will need a good understanding of formal grammars and natural languages before undertaking the project on your own, so first read up as much as you can on those and the related.** – Kris

I'd think no answer is going to benefit you at this stage.

Comment: Computational linguistics and natural language processing are *definitely* on topic at Linguistics.SE - but I would caution you, as @Kris notes, that Ling.SE is an experts forum.