# Should EL&U offer free English lessons?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is EL&U becoming ESL?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/703/is-elu-becoming-esl)

For one or two questioners, EL&U seems to be becoming a free source of English lessons for foreign learners. Is this consistent with the site's purpose?

Comment: @MetaEd: That was a year ago. Still no policy, presumably.

Comment: Per various conversations I've seen on MSO, I don't think EL&U should be an ESL site (because the site is for "language enthusiasts", etc. etc.) So, a -1 to show disagreement with the premise as stated (but not because it's a bad question by any means)

Comment: To answer for the moment asked, I agree that it seems like there are a handful of ESL learners who use ELU in the way mentioned. I think as usual the usual principles of voting manage those questions well enough. That is, where those questions are consistent with the site's purpose, the questions are voted well and answered well, and for questions not consistent they are down voted. Vote up/down as you see fit. To me, some of those questions are very interesting, and some ... not at all.

Comment: I've been active on ELU for less than a year, but it does seem to me the site has gone downhill in two major areas. Trivial stuff (questions about jokes, the minutiae of technical terminology interesting to people working in software, etc.), and really basic questions asked by people with limited skills in English. That second type usually come from non-native speakers - not that I'd want to discourage such users in general, but we're not running an ESL study aid here!

Comment: @simchona The problem is not the questions asked as if the site is an ESL site; the problem is the too basic, or too localized questions. I see also a problem with questions asking for a single word, in some cases; probably those questions are also asked from users who speak languages for which a single word can express what in English is expressed with a phrase.